# Inheriting typehints from parent super method in Python

Tags: python

I would like to add type hinting to a child class that does some additional validation before running.  If the parent method is properly type hinted, is there a way to inherit all of the typing?  If the parent method changes its interface or defaults for kwargs, I would like to not have to change all of the children class methods.  Is there a way to do this or a better way to implement, maybe with decorators?

Here's the two options I've tried so far:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Optional

@dataclass
class Parent():
    def print_list(self, list: List[float], sep:str= ", "):
        print(sep.join([str(item) for item in list]))


@dataclass
class Child(Parent): 
    allowed_to_print: bool
    
    # Proper typehints, but defaults can be different than parent if parent defaults change.
    def print_list(self, list: List[float], sep: str = ", "):
        if self.allowed_to_print: 
            super().print_list(list, sep)
        else:
            print("No")


@dataclass
class ChildNoDefaults(Parent): 
    allowed_to_print: bool

    #No typehints, but defaults come from the parent class
    def print_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.allowed_to_print: 
            super().print_list(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("No")
```

Comment: How much control over `Parent` do you have? I feel like the check should be in `Parent.print_list`, with `Parent.__init__` hard-coding the value of `allowed_to_print` to `True` with child classes having the option of overriding that, either on its own or via a user-supplied value. (Aaaaand, I see the first answer suggests something similar.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in Python, and I don't know of a clean way around it like other truly object-oriented languages allow the extension of method signatures with type checks intact. Although I will say that it's mainly a problem when you look at it from principle. In practice, for good Python use cases, I find it rarely becomes a real problem (perhaps creating the need for some annoying repetition and maintenance in those cases).

Having said that, there's an argument to be made that `print_list` no longer being guaranteed to actually print the list is a good reason to implement a new method with a different name (e.g. `checked_print_list`), that will call `print_list` if conditions are met, and print `No` otherwise.

If you want things to work the way you described, consider moving the actual work to a hidden method and overriding that. This implementation maintains the interface from the parent class and works as expected:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Optional


@dataclass
class Parent:
    DEFAULT_SEP = ", "

    def _print_list(self, items, sep):
        print(sep.join([str(item) for item in items]))

    def print_list(self, items: List[float], sep: Optional[str] = None):
        self._print_list(items, self.DEFAULT_SEP if sep is None else sep)


@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    DEFAULT_SEP = ". "

    allowed_to_print: bool

class Child(Parent):
    DEFAULT_SEP = ". "

    allowed_to_print: bool

    def _print_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.allowed_to_print:
            super()._print_list(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("No")


c_no = Child(allowed_to_print=False)
c_yes = Child(allowed_to_print=True)

c_no.print_list([1, 2, 3])  # correct type hints
c_yes.print_list([1, 2, 3])  # correct type hints and using correct changed default
```

Output:

```
No
1. 2. 3
```

This does have the disadvantage that the default is no longer in the signature. If you want that, you could do that, but then overriding the default in the child class becomes tricky, as you can't tell whether you're getting the default because it was not passed, or because the user just happened to explicitly pass a value that matches the default.

I.e.:

```
c_yes.print_list([1, 2, 3], ', ')
```

In this case, you'd want it to use `', '` as a separator, not the new default, even though the value matches the parent default.

Note I updated the answer to follow your use of `*args` and `**kwargs` - the advantage is clear, but you could also opt to implement an abstract parent class that requires a `_print_list` be present with as certain signature, to ensure anyone inheriting from it actually updates their implementation, if something changes upstairs - it's a choice, not a given.

(Just a note: don't call your variables names that shadow builtins, keywords, etc. - i.e. `list` is a very bad name for a variable and your editor should be warning you)

Comment: the parent class is maintained by a different team and is a more robust and generic class that is intended to be subclassed for more specific use cases.  Getting changes into the parent class will be more difficult that updating the child class which i'm directly maintaining.  In the subclass i'm working on, there are a number of methods that will not be supported if certain flags on the subclass instance's properties are true or false.

Noted on the variable names, that was just due to writing some quick example code.  Strange that vscode didn't complain about it.

Comment: If you cannot get changes into the parent class, I can only come up with ways to replicate the parent class' method signature for runtime use, which doesn't help since you're after coding / compile time use.